# CRAFT_CONFIG_PATH not picked up

Tags: plugin-development, plugins

I haves dev setup of a site that i want separate craft config, db and plugin folders for.

```
define('CRAFT_CONFIG_PATH', '../../../craftdevconfig/');
define('CRAFT_PLUGINS_PATH', '../../../craftdevplugins/');
define('CRAFT_STORAGE_PATH', '../../../craftdevstorage/'); //'../storage/');
define('CRAFT_TEMPLATES_PATH', '../craft/templates/');
```

I am trying to debug a plugin in craftdevconfig.

However I am having a nightmare knowing where craft is looking.
For my plugin it seems to get its default configuration from the live craft/plugins folder. But for code changes, seems to change its mind about where the plugin service calls should be found. I can debug it locally as it has IP based service calls to third parties. Slowly going bald.

Any ideas on how to clarify where craft thinks stuff is would be great

Comment: Not sure I'm following 100%.  `CRAFT_CONFIG_PATH` just allows you to override where the `craft/config` folder lives by default.  "I am trying to debug a plugin in craftdevconfig." Are you saying your plugin is providing its own config settings and you're having a hard time figuring out how to provide those?

Comment: Im saying - to craft - here is my plugin folder 
define('CRAFT_PLUGINS_PATH', '../../../craftdevplugins/');
and its getting its settings from '../../../craft/plugins/[name]/config.php

Answer (score 1):

A plugin that has config settings can provide the default values for those settings in `plugins/pluginHandle/config.php`.

Since you've defined `CRAFT_PLUGINS_PATH` as `craftdevplugins`, that would be `craftdevplugins\pluginHandle\config.php`.

End users can set can set custom values in `config/pluginHandle.php`.  Since you've defined `CRAFT_CONFIG_PATH` as `craftdevconfig`, that would be `craftdevconfig\pluginHandle.php`.